# context_click() not working in headless chrome - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to right-click on a webpage using selenium context_click(). When I am doing this in normal mode, the context_click() is working, but in headless mode, it is not working. Doing this on chromedriver.
Here is the headless mode configuration,

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1088,1088")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
```

And this is the code I am using to do context_click():

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# action chain object creation
action = ActionChains(driver)

action.move_by_offset(200, 200)
# right click operation and then perform
action.context_click().perform()
#get screenshot
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/content/screenshot3.png")
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to share url of the page?

Comment: Hi @Himanshuman here is the URL, https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/sport/football/football-news/manchester-united-atletico-madrid-highlights-24628643
But no matter which URL I am using, the context_click() is not working. Even tried on google.com

Comment: So you would expect the context click menu window to appear in screenshot? Did you test this with normal (non-headless) browser, see if it appears in screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that @platipus_on_fire. It works.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal, why would you need a screenshot with a context menu?

Comment: I dont need a screenshot with the context menu. I just require the context_click() to work. The screenshot is there just to see if it is actually performing the action. @platipus_on_fire